# Azure Devops running iOS XCUITests gives "Failed to start launchd_sim:"

Tags: xcode, azure-devops, xcuitest

When running my XCUITests on Azure Devops and I use 2 simulators, I get the following  error:

```
Unable to boot the Simulator. launchd failed to respond. (Underlying Error: Failed to start launchd_sim: could not bind to session, launchd_sim may have crashed or quit responding)))
```

When I use one simulator it works. Is there a way to reset the simulator are delete deviated data? Any other idea what could help is highly appreciated.

EDIT: Here are the 2 simulators I run:

```
destinations: |
  platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 8,OS=15.4
  platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 14,OS=16.1
```

I first ran them maxParallel: 4. Now I reduced to maxParallel: 1 with the result that it sometimes works and sometimes not. Really strange.
In the Xcode project I use a testplan where "Execute in parallel (if possible)" is not checked.

Comment: Can you provide more detail on "use two simulators"? Are you running in parallel? How are you specifying that?

Comment: @MikeCollins I added some information you asked for in the question. Any idea?

Comment: I've not used Azure Devops, but I've written at length about the limitations of CircleCI and iOS parallelization. The short of it is that it's hard for them to do and they likely don't fully support it even if they claim they do. https://www.iammike.org/2021/03/04/xcuitest-circleci-and-parallelization/

Comment: Thanks @MikeCollins that's what I feel as well (parallelisation). I've removed it where I can and interestingly test run faster then. Unfortunately that didn't fix my initial flakiness problem. I'm still investigating.

Comment: Yeah, CI “just runs differently.” It will be a regular occurrence where something runs fine locally and flakes in CI. This does not differ across vendors. If you can specify a “metal” instance (you get a physical box to yourself) you will be able to mitigate a lot of this.

Comment: @Mike Collins We are definitely considering getting a real Mac for the tests. As you also said, our impression is, that those VMs are just not powerful enough to do this kind of stuff.
However: my colleague found an optional parameter in "test.steps.yml": "-maximum-concurrent-test-simulator-destinations". Setting it to one seems to cure some flakiness.